# xelatex doesn't work properly with tikz when pgfpage with \pgfpagesuselayout is used!

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, pgfpages

I'm trying to make a fading background using tikz. It works great with `pdflatex`, but when I use `xelatex` it doesn't work properly.

As I noticed the problem is because of `\pgfpagesuselayout` command. I need it because I want to make a poster and its size should more and more larger than the original size like a4paper or something like that. 
In below example I've used a4paper just for showing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{pgf}%
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}%

\usepackage{pgfpages}%
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \shade [top color=yellow,bottom color=red!50] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);%
\end{tikzpicture}

\centerline{\Huge Hi Parsi\LaTeX{}}
\end{document}
```

the correct result that is produced with `pdflatex`:
[image]

and the odd result with ‍‍‍‍‍‍`xelatex`:
[image]

I don't know it is a bug for xelatex or xelatex driver of tikz?!

P.S.
I use TeXLive2015. 
Someone else that tested this code with TeXLive2012 had not such a problem!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I can confirm this is a regression from TL 2012; with TL 2013 the colored box is shifted down, with TL 2014 and 2015 the result is as you show. With TL 2012 I get the warning `Your graphic driver pgfsys-xetex.def does not support fadings.` that disappears with later versions.

Comment: What should I do? 
Who can help to fix it?

Comment: If it is of any help, I find that this works correctly with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: thanks for the test with LuaLaTeX, but because of some packages,e.g. bidi, I just need the xelatex.

Comment: Could someone tell me where I should report this bug?

Answer (score 2):

A similar output as that of pdflatex is obtained by xelatex
with the following for your special example.
Don't expect that it is applicable to other cases.

```
%
% xelatex
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
%
\def\pdftexversion{140}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
%
\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@papersize#1#2{%
  \pdfpageheight#2\relax%
  \pdfpagewidth#1\relax}
\makeatother
%
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \shade [top color=yellow,bottom color=red!50] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);%
\end{tikzpicture}

\centerline{\Huge Hi Parsi\LaTeX{}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def, which is called by
pgfsys-xetex.def, should be updated by someone
who knows details on tikz, xetex, xdvipdfmx,...